# Not to hardcode in annotations

Tags: java, spring

**Utils**

```
public class GeneralUtils {    

    public static String getUrlWithId(String urlsPartStr) {
        // Get a relative URL like /delete/{id} .
        String result = String.format("%s/{id}", urlsPartStr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**UrlsParts**

```
public class UrlsParts {   

    public static final String delete = "/delete";

    public static final String deleteById = GeneralUtils.getUrlWithId(delete);

}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(UrlsParts.deleteById)
public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id,
                     Model model) {
    authorRepository.deleteById(id);

    return "redirect:" + Urls.AUTHORS_LIST.getHref();
}
```

I am using Spring here. But anyway, the question is about core Java.

**Error**

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Problem**

I try not to hardcode strings in annotations. In the last video there is a partial solution. I have not been able to succeed.

Any solution will suit me (enums etc.).

Comment: How about `public static final String deleteById = delete + "/{id}";`? Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Not much you can do. You're trying to compute something at runtime (even if the output is functionally a constant), which annotations don't like. I'd say that for these kind of thing hardcoding the string is the right thing to do. You're (imho) overcomplicating something that doesn't need to be complicated.

Comment: @Sweeper, it will work. But this is only a partial solution. Anyway, DRY principle will be violated as next it will be list + "/{id}. And anyway there is a clearly visible pattern whicn I want to generalize in a method.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, but the solution suggested by Sweeper will work. It is also computed. I can't see the difference.

Comment: The difference is that calling a method makes the filed "not constant". The method has to be evaluated at runtime, and can't be computed at compile time. On the other hand, the compiler knows very well how to evaluate `delete + "/{id}"` at compile time.

Comment: @Kifsif because it's concatenating two string constants. That's a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) and that's ok for the annotation.

Comment: How about declaring another constant called `byId = "/{id}"` and write `delete + byId`? That looks pretty nice, doesn't it?

Comment: Specifically the difference is that annotation values must be **constant expressions** [as defined by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29), because they are stored as constant values inside the class files. The JVM spec/class file format specification simply doesn't provide a way to indicate a annotation property value needs to be retrieved by calling a method.

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you. You seem to be right. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the argument for an annotation must be a constant expression. You can see the definition of a "constant" expression in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly

It then goes on to list the necessary and sufficient conditions for a constant expression. Here are some of the relevant ones:

> (a constant expression) is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4), string literals (§3.10.5), and text blocks (§3.10.6)
> - The additive operators `+` and `-` (§15.18)
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
> - Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
> - [...]

And a "constant variable" is [(§4.12.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.29).

Notably, method calls are not constant expressions. One reason is that methods could "complete abruptly", by throwing an exception for example.

Therefore, `deleteById` is not a constant variable, and so the expression `deleteById` is not a constant expression.

On the other hand, the expressions `delete + "/{id}"` *is* a constant expression because `delete` and `"/{id}"` are constant expressions, and `+` applied to constant expressions is also a constant expression.

I'd suggest declaring a separate constant called `byId`, if you don't want to repeatedly write `"/{id}"`.

```
public static final String byId = "/{id}";
public static final String deleteById = delete + byId;
```

Or use `delete + byId` directly as the annotation argument.